# How can I pass rgb color to OnPhotonSerializeView (Photon Network)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I need to pass rgb variables to OnPhotonSerializeView.

I tried to do it like this:

```
    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
{
    if (stream.IsWriting)
    {
        stream.SendNext(healthCircle.color.r);
        stream.SendNext(healthCircle.color.g);
        stream.SendNext(healthCircle.color.b);
    }
    else 
    {
        healthCircle.color.r = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
        healthCircle.color.g = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
        healthCircle.color.b = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
    }
}
```

After this i get an error:

```
Assets\Scripts\Player.cs(68,13): error CS1612: Cannot modify the return value of 'SpriteRenderer.color' because it is not a variable
```

I tried to search it in google but i didn't find anything. Sorry for my noob question. Waiting for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SpriteRenderer.color` (as most things in Unity) is a **property** which either returns or takes a complete `Color` as assignment.

In addition to that `Color` is a `struct` so a copy by value, not a reference type so even if you **could** do this what **would** happen here is

- You return the current `healthCircle.color`
- On this returned `Color` value you assign e.g. `r = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();`

=> So this

- **would** always return a new `Color` instance, a copy of the current one and assign only the one component there
- **would** have no effect since the `healthCircle.color` is never actually assigned a new value

What you want to do is rather either

```
var color = healthCircle.color;
color.r = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
color.g = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
color.b = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
healthCircle.color = color;
```

or directly do

```
healthCircle.color = new Color((float)stream.ReceiveNext(), (float)stream.ReceiveNext(), (float)stream.ReceiveNext());
```